# What is the scope of PHP set_time_limit()?

Tags: php

I still don't fully understand how set_time_limit() works, and the documentation didn't say anything about scope.
Lets say I have the following code:

```
public function fetchSomething()
{
    //this runs for 10 seconds
    return $fetchedData;
}

public function doSomething()
{
    set_time_limit(101);
    //do stuff for 50 seconds
    $this->fetchSomething();
    //do stuff for another 50 seconds
}
```

Will this run out of time limit and throw an exception because doSomething() runs for 50+10+50 seconds, or will doSomething() runs for 50+50 (while fetchSomething() is timed separately)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/php-in-a/0596100671/re82.html):

> When you use this function, the script timer is reset to 0; if you set 50 as the time limit, then after 40 seconds set the time limit to 30, the script will run for 70 seconds in total. That said, most web servers have their own time limit over and above PHP’s. In Apache, this is set under Timeout in httpd.conf, and defaults to 300 seconds. If you use set_time_limit() to a value greater than Apache’s timeout value, Apache will stop PHP before PHP stops itself. PHP may let some scripts go over the time limit if control is outside the script. For example, if you run an external program that takes 100 seconds and you have set the time limit to 30 seconds, PHP will let the script carry on for the full 100 seconds and terminate immediately afterwards. This also happens if you use the sleep() function with a value larger than the amount of time the script has left to execute.

Answer (score 0):

it lasts the life of the script - and inside the script it will have the affect of 101 seconds from when that was called

Answer (score 0):

It sets the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the `max_execution_time` value defined in the `php.ini`.

When called, `set_time_limit()` restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as `set_time_limit(20)` is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Read the official document: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)